# What is that device on an Su-27 pilot's helmet?

Tags: feature-identification, equipment, helmet, su-27

While watching a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZvMljUNCeU&t=56s) (2.5hrs), I noticed this device on the top of most Russian Su-27 combat pilot's helmet. A google search only shows it for a Su-27 and MiG-29, but apparently no other aircraft. It was not on any Chinese, Syria, Ukraine or Russian aerobatic pilots flying the Su-27. It appears to be at the wrong angle and has a metal plate that seems to exclude it from being some type of illumination.

What is this on a Su-27 helmet?

[image]

Comment: Possibly a night vision goggle bracket?

Comment: Looks like a go-pro mount.

Comment: Unrelated, but thank you for the documentary link. Truly interesting.

Comment: Russian Su-27 combat fighter aircraft designed around 1980. It started out as a lemon but the Russians improved it and variants so quickly over a few years that it soon out flew any other aircraft in the world. The F22 and F35 have been built specifically as a deterrent to the S-27 & Su-35. Russia challenged the US to a test dogfight. ***The US pilots did not like the idea...much, too risky to hold the fight...in front of photographers and TV cameras.***
http://www.pravdareport.com/world/americas/20-07-2009/108253-su27-0/

Comment: @jwzumwalt we sure that's not an urban legend/ pravda piece?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That is the mounting point for night vision goggles. The following image shows a helmet with NVG mounted.

[image: Helmet mounted NVG]

Helmet mounted NVG; image from [lemt.by](http://lemt.by/en/ochki-nochnogo-videniya-nv-g-a/)

The USAF has helmets with different mounting and some of the modern pilot helmets (like [BAE Striker II](https://www.baesystems.com/en/product/striker-ii-digital-helmet-mounted-display), for example) have an integrated night vision device.

Answer (score 3):

[image]
([spetstechnoexport.com](http://spetstechnoexport.com/catalogues/145))

Those are also mounts for Helmet Mounted Sight for the [Vympel R-73 missile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-73_(missile)). Both the MiG-29 and Su-27 were equipped with this missile system.

I think F-35 pilots have this technology now but with a fancier helmet. The old ones on the MIGs looks like monocle.

Comment: Can you provide any information on this targeting wearable device? Such as its name, and any supporting material? Thanks.

Comment: @ymb [SURA helmet-mounted target designator](http://spetstechnoexport.com/catalogues/145) is the Su-30-adapted export version of "Щель-3УМ-1" system, which is used on MiG-29 and Su-27 (and its derivatives). It is indeed can be mounted on that slot on the helmet.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov - nice info, I added the picture from the link.